# How to get ANTLR 4 to exit upon first lexing or parsing error?

Tags: exception, error-handling, antlr4

I'm trying to solve this same problem as in [How to get ANTLR 3.2 to exit upon first error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445008/how-to-get-antlr-3-2-to-exit-upon-first-error) but in antlr4 since there's no recoverFromMismatchedToken()

Answer (score 1):

Antlr4 typically uses the [`ANTLRErrorStrategy` interface](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorStrategy.java). Look at the [`BailErrorStrategy`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BailErrorStrategy.java) in particular.

To bail on a lexer error immediately, override the two `recover(....)` methods in the [Lexer class](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.java). Do this by implementing (1) lexer member methods; or (2) creating a Lexer superclass containing the override methods.

Comment: I already did that but it doesn't exit upon error if it's a lexing error.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, GRosenberg!

I downloaded the BailErrorStrategy.java file (see GRosenberg's note above).

I then stopped using the default Lexer, and created my own simple Sub-class Lexer as:-

```
package ...;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.LexerNoViableAltException;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException;

public class MyYAMLANTLR4Lexer extends YAMLANTLR4Lexer {
    public MyYAMLANTLR4Lexer(CharStream input) {
        super(input);
    }
    public void recover(LexerNoViableAltException e) { }
    public void recover(RecognitionException re) { }
}
```